# FlashBuilder workspace update issues

Tags: actionscript-3, ide, flash-builder, workspace

When working on several AS3 projects that share a common code base, FlashBuilder seems to be losing workspace data when switching from one project to the next. I will often get a message that such class could not be found , when the class is actually in the path but was probably modified in the previous project.

To fix this error, I find myself having to remove the external library folder , restart FB, then re-add the library folder and all is well.

Please tell me there's another way to "refresh" FB's workspace ! Have you experienced anything similar? If yes, how do you avoid this problem?

Comment: I know some similar problems from Flex Builder ( [FB-22066](http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-22066) ), but they should had fixed in Flash Builder.

Comment: i have some problems too when i change the http services base url... it seems that the functions parameters get lose but when i refresh the project a couple times they appear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try a clean on the project?

project -> clean

You could also try to clean your workspace.  In windows for example, just add -clean after the link to the exe.

**Update:**

on a mac, try this: http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2007/06/30/run-eclipse-from-the-command-line-on-os-x/

Comment: Project clean doesn't do it and I'm using a Mac!

Comment: Interesting article. I will definitely try although I doubt this is the issue because my FB4 version is a fairly recent install, not even a month old... +1 for the tip!

Comment: I checked your link & some other related articles , changed workspace, clean via the command line... the problem persists. I'll put that down to Eclipse weirdness...